# jquery validating html (remove p tags inside h1 tags etc) Remove tags keep the content

Tags: jquery, html, tags

can any one help me with this jquery, i need to remove tags inside other tags eg if a p tag is inside an h1 tag remove the p tag but keep the content, I have tried a few ways but the best i can come up with is to remove the content as well

```
$("#textEditor").contents().find("h1:has(p)").find("p").remove();
```

Edit here is the mark up i would like to validate

```
    <h1>This is an example <strong> of bad markup</strong> 
<p>need to remove these p tags but keep content</p></h1>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `unwrap()` to remove a tag, but keep it's content in the DOM. Also, your call to the `contents()` function isn't required.

```
$("#textEditor").find("h1:has(p)").find("p").unwrap();
```

[More details on unwrap()](http://api.jquery.com/unwrap/)

Comment: Thank you for the help, unwrap seems to be removing the h1 tags and keeping the p tags

Comment: Could you please edit your OP and post the HTML you're using so I can see how it's structured.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you i just worked it out

```
 $("#textEditor").contents().find("h1:has(p)").find("p").contents().unwrap();
```

Thank you for pointing out the unwrap, the contents was needed because the #textEditor is in a iframe